# Excel Get Column Headers

Tags: c#, excel

I have a function to get excel sheet column names.

```
 DataTable dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null,"BOLT$" , null });

   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
       MessageBox.Show((string)row["COLUMN_NAME"]);
   }
```

But this function is getting column names as F1, F2 .. whereas my actual column headers are LineNo, DateOfPurchase ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832001/in-c-sharp-how-to-access-excel-headers-using-oledb-without-automation

Comment: @hob thank you. I got the issue. Problem was with connection string. HDR is set to NO earlier. Now I changed it to HDR=YES. everything works fine.

Comment: great glad to be of help :)